DS 160 help for B2 visa
My wife and I have a USA B2 visa which expires in August 2025. However I have decided to apply again this month. She will apply after 2 months.
My query is what should I mention for the question "Is anyone traveling with you?" Should I say "No" even though my wife will be traveling with me since she's not applying right now and our travel dates will be Sept 2025.
And when she fills her application should she say "Yes" for the same question since I would have received the visa by then hopefully?

Imagine you were travelling with someone who does not need a visa. What would you answer?

Why would you answer "No" when you have just clearly said that she's traveling with you?  "Is anyone traveling with you?"  "Yes"

The question is whether someone is traveling with you. You just said that someone is. What does her visa application have to do with the question? What is your motivation to lie to the visa officer here?

Yes but this is assuming she doesnt have a visa. Why should i say yes whn she doesnt have a visa on those dates?

Are you planning to go with her or not? That's the question, not whether she has a visa or not.

Yes i am planning to go with her.

The answer is "yes."  The fact that your wife will apply for a visa after you does not change the fact that you plan to travel together.

Yes i am planning to go with her

Should the new travel dates be post the visa expiry date

@Mohd you're planning to travel with her after her visa expires.  She's planning to apply for a new visa before then.  Why would you think that you should answer "no" to the question?  Obviously your plan is contingent on her visa application being successful.

Ur right. Then i guess yes would be the right answer
